# Angular ui layout - how to refresh sizes when something changes?

Tags: angularjs

I recently started using [angular ui-layout](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout)
I have a 3-pane view. The rightmost pane is optional and is only shown sometimes, I hide and show it with `ng-if`.

If the ng-if evaluates to false, the size is not recalculated and the middle pane doesn't take the rest of the horizontal space.

```
<ui-layout options="{ flow: 'column' }">
     <div ui-layout-container size="15%"> sidebar </div>
     <div ui-layout-container min-size="65%"> main </div>
     <div ui-layout-container ng-if="haveSelected()" size="20%"> props </div>
</ui-layout>
```

If the `ng-if` is false, main takes up all the space after the sidebar, if it becomes true, the space for the 3rd pane is allocated correctly, but if it becomes false again, the space is not reclaimed.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Comment: I am having the same issue.
It does not refresh until you slightly resize the browser size.
Actually the css width of the div is not getting updated.
Please let me know if anyone have found any solution to this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a better solution, but you can put your `ng-if` test on two `div`s with the `ui-layout` element with opposite Boolean evaluations.  This isn't that bad of a solution for my situation because I am using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).

Example (in Jade):

```
ui-layout(options="{ flow: 'column' }", ng-if="showThirdPanel")
  div(ui-layout-container)
    include ./firstPanel.jade
  div(ui-layout-container)
    include ./secondPanel.jade
  div(ui-layout-container)
    include ./thirdPanel.jade
ui-layout(options="{ flow: 'column' }", ng-if="!showThirdPanel")
  div(ui-layout-container)
    include ./firstPanel.jade
  div(ui-layout-container)
    include ./secondPanel.jade
```